# Use global class object from one module in other in Delphi

Tags: class, object, oop, delphi

I want one class object to be a global variable in one module in Delphi, and other modules(.pas-files, maybe it's not correct to call it a module, I'm not really familiar with Delphi) be able to use this global variable. Is it a way to initialize global object not inside some global function and have other modules use this global object directly? Without any global functions. Is it possible?

Comment: How about reading a beginner's Delphi book or tutorial?

Comment: @MartynA I'm searching in http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/ and reading it, but so far I haven't found an answer to my question. Search there doesn't work great at all

Comment: Well, you're basically asking about the visibility/accessibilityof objects/classes between source files.  THat's basically a tutorial topic and tutorials are off-topic here.

Comment: A recent version of the Object Pascal Handbook by Marco Cantu is one option. Fairly inexpensive as an Amazon Kindle eBook or often as a free eBook with the purchase of Delphi.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply declare the variable in the unit's `interface`, and then use that unit in other units' `uses` clauses as needed.  You can initialize the variable in its unit's `initialization` section.

UnitA.pas:

```pascal
unit A;

interface

type
  TMyClass = class
    // members as needed...
  end;

var
  GlobalObj: TMyClass;

implementation

// implement TMyClass methods as needed...

initialization
  GlobalObj := TMyClass.Create;
finalization
  GlobalObj.Free;

end.
```

UnitB.pas:

```pascal
unit B;

...

uses
  ..., A;

// use A.GlobalObj as needed...

end.
```